# Не отправляются данные из FSMContext

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Есть код:

```
async def get_form(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Здравствуйте, я бот Estrolife, я могу помочь вам с решением вашего вопроса. '
                         'Выберите, пожалуйста, к какой теме относится ваш вопрос.', reply_markup=get_reply_keyboard())
    await state.update_data(theme=message.text)
    await state.set_state(StopsForm.GET_THEME)


async def get_question(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f'Выбранная тема "{message.text}". Задайте любой вопрос по данной теме,'
                         f' и мы с радостью вам ответим')
    await state.update_data(question=message.text)
    await state.set_state(StopsForm.GET_QUESTION)


async def get_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f'Оставьте свои контактные данные, чтобы мы могли направить ответ на ваш вопрос. '
                         f'Имя:')
    await state.update_data(name=message.text)
    await state.set_state(StopsForm.GET_NAME)


async def get_phone(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f'Телефон:')
    await state.update_data(phone=message.text)
    await state.set_state(StopsForm.GET_PHONE)


async def get_email(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f'Электронная почта:')
    await state.update_data(email=message.text)
    await state.set_state(StopsForm.GET_EMAIL)


async def get_info(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f'Отлично, отправляя свой вопрос, Вы даёте согласие на обработку свои персональных данных.',
                         reply_markup=get_keyboard())
    await state.set_state(StopsForm.GET_INFO)


async def get_last(message: Message, state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
    await message.answer(f'Cкоро с Вами свяжется наш менеджер, ожидайте.')
    await state.set_state(StopsForm.GET_LAST)


async def get_manage(message: Message, bot: Bot, state: FSMContext):
    context_data = await state.get_data()
    theme = context_data.get('theme')
    question = context_data.get('question')
    name = context_data.get('name')
    phone = context_data.get('phone')
    email = context_data.get('email')
    user_data = (f'Новый вопрос \r\n'
                 f'Тема: {theme} \r\n'
                 f'Вопрос: {question} \r\n'
                 f'Имя: {name} \r\n'
                 f'Телефон: {phone} \r\n'
                 f'Email: {email}')
    await bot.send_message(6057230955, user_data)
    await state.clear()
```

Как видите после получения всех данных бот должен был отправить их админу, то есть мне ,но ничего не приходит, работает все правильно, но бот ничего не отправляет, что я сделал не так?

Comment: Что в консоли? Ошибка возникает какая-нибудь? Проверяли на промежуточных шагах, содержатся ли какие-нибудь данные после записи?

Comment: Спасибо уже решил